# Graphic User Interface

Tags: user-interface

Is there a way to make a more elegant UI easily? (Maybe something like Google Chrome)

Is there a framework or something do this?

--EDIT

It would be best in Python/Java/C++.
I don't mind learning something new.

Comment: There are a lot of tools for this, need to be more specific about at least the language you want, and what the goal is.

Comment: It would be best in Python/Java/C++. I don't mind learning something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is known as "Rapid Application Development" or RAD. Under RAD, graphical user interfaces (GUIs) are developed using a What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get (WYSIWYG) GUI editing software.

In practice, most of these tools are imperfect and still require some manual modification of the generated code. So, even when using these tools, you should consider them to be more of an aid to automation or simplification of your workflow but not a complete replacement for writing UI code.

For Android applications (which are typically written in Java), the [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) IDE comes with a mechanism for creating some parts of the UI via drag-and-drop. For iOS, Apple's Xcode tools package includes [Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/interface-builder/), which lets you construct the UI for iOS apps via drag-and-drop. For web applications, the [Polymer Designer](https://polymer-designer.appspot.com/) and [Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) may be of interest.

Not that you should be writing native desktop applications, but if you are... For Java, the [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) IDE features a very high quality GUI editor which generates Java code using the Java Swing classes. For C++, [QtCreator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/) features a high quality GUI editor using the Qt framework.

Comment: If you are using netbeans I would recommend using the editor to create JavaFX interfaces instead of swing applications.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite GUI designing software is Microsoft Visual Studio. It's very simple, literally drag and drop GUI design. While Visual Studio as a whole isn't free, different free "express" editions are available. The only difference is with the express editions is that you're limited to a single language. I would recommend trying out Visual C# Express which can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/

As for the C# language, it's a blend of C++ and Java. It's very easy to pick up if you've used either language before and is well documented at www.msdn.com.